# Installing angular2-localstorage in WebStorm gives error regarding "typings install"

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm, npm-install

I am using windows and WebStorm. Tried to install `angular2-localstorage` with `npm install angular2-localstorage` but got an error.

The `angular2-localstorage` project is not maintained, so I'm posting here.

https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localStorage

Error details:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular2-localstorage"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! angular2-localstorage@0.4.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-localstorage@0.4.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-localstorage package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-localstorage
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-localstorage
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\***\WebstormProjects\ReusGooRoo2\npm-debug.log
```

The log file contents: http://pastebin.com/njG9XMgK

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you have a typings installed global?

Answer (score 0):

Since the node module `angular2-localstorage` is not maintained properly, I would recommend angular-2-local-storage node_module as an alternative.

Steps:

1. Install `npm install angular-2-local-storage`
2. Make sure that the package is added in the config.js(systemjs or webpack)
3. Import the module and service as below

   ```
   import { LocalStorageModule,LocalStorageService} from 'angular-2-local-storage';
   ```
4. Add the module to imports array and service to providers array as

   ```
    imports: [ BrowserModule,
      LocalStorageModule.withConfig({storageType: 'localStorage'}), ],

    providers:[LocalStorageService],
   ```
5. Inject the Service as a dependency into component as below

   ```
   constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
           this.name = 'Angular-2-Local-Storage-Demo';
           this.localStorageService.add('a',this.user);
           console.log(this.localStorageService.get('a')); 
           this.valuFromLocalStorage= this.localStorageService.get('a')
   }
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BOIyDOKgWey6UbNZrnAl?p=preview)**